# vba code for printout option is not working for me

Tags: vba

I have error while trying to give printout action, if any solution provided will be helpful...

```
Dim objTextStream
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextStream = fso.opentextfile("E:\NewFile.prn")`
objTextStream.PrintOut(1) 

// not executing
```

#### Debug error

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to refer to a specific line in a textstream however you can loop through all lines as per my answer below. If you include a counter then you can choose to only write specific lines as you iterate through them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no print method in a `TextStream` object (this is what `opentextfile` returns). 
To print a file, you have to use a Windows API function `apiShellExecute`.

This is copied from http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1066955-How-do-i-print-a-txt-file-with-VBA (but untested):

Place the following in the declaration section of a module (at the top) if you place it in a standard module, change Private to Public:

```
Private Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
As Long
```

Then in the routine where you need to print, call it with:

```
lngReturn = apiShellExecute(hWndAccessApp, "print", strFileAndPath, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
```

where `strFileAndPath` is your filename (eg `"E:\NewFile.prn"`)

Comment: Sometimes the apishellexecute command is bypassed in scriptworx, can't debug the problem.

Comment: the code is being exported to access. please let me know how to make printout to printer device

Comment: can we perform printout action using vba code? (want to give printout to printer directly through vba code)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each line of the read file like this. You can then either `debug.print` that line or write it to a separate write file as shown.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Dim FSO, FileIn, FileOut As Object
Dim strTmp As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FileIn = FSO.OpenTextFile("E:\NewFile.prn", ForReading)
Set FileOut = FSO.OpenTextFile("E:\NewWriteFile.prn", ForWriting, True)

Do Until FileIn.AtEndOfStream
    strTmp = FileIn.ReadLine
    FileOut.WriteLine strTmp
Loop

FileIn.Close
FileOut.Close
```